# Fonts displaying wrongly bold-italic in all browsers on one computer

Tags: support

I have a very strange problem with math.stackexchange.com. The normal text on the pages (and on these meta pages, too) is displaying in both IE and Chrome in bold italics on just one of my computers. I have a couple of other computers, and the fonts display normally on those.

I did 'inspect element' in the Chrome browser, and it looks like the font family chain is Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, etc.; nothing about bold and italics, so it looks like the pages are ok.

The displays are the same (both wrongly bold italic) in Internet Explorer and in Google Chrome, so it doesn't look like a browser issue.

The computer is super vanilla, many fewer applications installed on it than on the others, so I think it's unlikely to be something broken in Windows on the computer.

The MathJax formulas display correctly, it's just the normal text is off.

I couldn't find any way to set default fonts in Google Chrome (I'm not a browser expert).

Could this be a "Themes" thing? Do Windows themes reach inside browsers? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I went into the Windows fonts interface in Control Panel, and the only variation of Georgia that was installed was the "Bold-Italic" variation, so that explains it. It appears that my computer was *so* vanilla that Hewlett-Packard decided, on my behalf, to remove fonts that I couldn't shouldn't wouldn't possibly ever want. After all, a couple of wasted megabytes from a rare font on my 1TB hard drive could be critical! (sarcasm). My attempt to copy the missing fonts from another computer has created some new problems.

ANSWER: Copying all fonts from another computer and **rebooting** fixed the problem for now.

Comment: For Chrome: did you check the [font settings "Under The Hood"](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416&from=95415&rd=1)?

Comment: FINAL UPDATE: Copying all fonts from another computer and **rebooting** fixed all problems for now.

Comment: @Reb: can you post your final answer as an answer and accept it? This way the QA format of the software will make it more obvious that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying all fonts from another computer via the fonts item in the control panel (which opens up a special kind of folder) and rebooting fixed the problem for now. Rebooting is a critical step -- there may be some other, less drastic way to "finalize" the font installation, but rebooting definitely did so.